# Read the coefficients a,b,c of the quadratic equation ax^2+bx+c and print it roots nicely for imaginary roots print in x+iy form

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int a, b, c, x, x1, x2;
    printf("enter the values of a,b,c:");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("The quadratic equation is %d*pow(x,2)+%d*x+%d=0", a, b, c);

    if (pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c >= 0) {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
        printf("the roots of the equation are x1=%d,x2=%d", x1, x2);
    }
    else
        printf("roots of the equation in the form of x+iy and x-iy");

    return 0;
}
```

Is this code alright for the given question, i had a bit confusion at that printing imaginary roots. could you please help

Comment: You should check that `scanf` succeeds. `if(scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) { success } else { failure }`

Comment: Sorry i didnt get your point, why it should be ==3

Comment: While it's okay for `a`, `b`, and `c` to be `int`, I'd think you'd want `x1` and `x2` to be `double` (and print with `%g`)

Comment: @user17725027 Read about what [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns and you'll understand why it should be `== 3`.

Comment: i am so sorry still i am not getting, my doubt is that what steps should i follow to print imaginary roots in the form of x+iy , ok that i understood x1 and x2 should be double but what about my doubt

Comment: Rather than using `double` for x1 and x2, you might want to consider using `double complex`.  Check out the macros and functions in `complex.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use proper `main` prototype.
2. Use floating point numbers instead of integers
3. pow(b,2) == b*b
4. `/ 2 * a` -> `/ (2 * a)`

```
int main(void) {
    double a, b, c, x, x1, x2;
    printf("enter the values of a,b,c:");
    if(scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c) != 3) { /* handle error */}
    printf("\nThe quadratic equation is %f*x^2+%f*x+%f=0\n", a, b, c);

    if (b*b - 4 * a * c >= 0) {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
        printf("the roots of the equation are x1=%f,x2=%f\n", x1, x2);
    }
    else
    {
        double r = -b / (2*a);
        double z = sqrt(fabs(b*b - 4 * a * c));

        printf("the roots of the equation are x1 = %f + i%f, x2 = %f - i%f", r,z,r,z);
    }
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ys1s8bWY7